# python import socket class from other modules

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, global-variables, python-import

I have created a class(object) **connection_manager** using socket TCP in a module (**connection.py**):

```
#file connection.py
HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 8001        # Port to listen on TCP/IP
PORT1 = 8002       # Port to listen on UDP/IP

class connection_manager(object):
    def creat_tcp_connection(self):
        try:
            self.client_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            tcp_server_address = (HOST, PORT)
        except:
            print("Serveur TCP Introuvable")
        finally:
            print('Connecting to TCP server:' + str(tcp_server_address))
            self.client_tcp.connect(tcp_server_address)
            print('Connection TCP sucessful')
        return self.client_tcp
```

Now I want to import this class into **test.py** to use this socket. So I did:

```
#file test
import socket
import sys
import connection as cnx

def test_function():
    try:      
        texte = "ABC\n"
        cnx.client_tcp.send(texte.encode())
        data=cnx.client_tcp.recv(1024)
    except:
        print("error occur")    
    finally: 
        print('closing test')
    
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    p1 = cnx.connection_manager()
    test_function()
```

But It got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'connection_manager' object has no attribute 'client_tcp'
```

In the same module, in test_function I can use:

```
self.client_tcp.send(texte.encode())
data=self.client_tcp.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
```

s
But in different modules, I don't know how to do it? How can I import the class using socket from this module into another module?
Many thanks

Comment: If both of your files are in same directory, you can import it using `from connection import *`

Comment: That the things I have done. import connetion as cnx

Comment: But the name of your file is `connection.py` not `connetion.py`

Comment: Thanks for correcting me the mistake, but it does not solve my problem.